# Selecting average and latest value of column on associated record using rails/activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have three models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :monthly_records
  belongs_to :store
end
```

I need want to create an index view where I show the following fields:

1. customer.id
2. customer.name
3. store.name
4. average of monthly_records.grand total where monthly_records.month_start > ? AND monthly_records.month_start <= ?
5. monthly_records.grand_total for a specific month that the user will supply through the controller

Because this is an index and I want to show many rows at a time I want to do this in a single query and avoid the N+1 problem.  I know how to do this with Customer.select.join.group if I take 1-3 and EITHER 4 or 5, but I can't figure out how to do all 5 at once.

I've found some pure SQL answers that look like they may work, but I'd prefer to keep this to activerecord if at all possible.

Using postgres 9.3.4 and rails 4.0.10.

Comment: Why do you want to keep it in activerecord? SQL's more efficient, especially as your data storage needs increase.

Comment: If you could propose a SQL solution and show me how to execute it in rails that would also work.  I'm just beginning to get into the guts of sql and have had trouble implementing the potential solutions I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, Can you try:

Controller:

```
@customers = Customer.
  select('customers.id,customers.name,monthly_records.grand_total,stores.name').
  includes(:store, :monthly_records).
  references(:stores, :monthly_records)
```

Try `Customer\` to see if dot can start the next lines:

```
@customers = Customer\
  .select('customers.id,customers.name,monthly_records.grand_total,stores.name')...
```

On view:

```
- @customers.each do |customer|
  - records = customer.monthly_records.\
      where('month_start > ? AND month_start <= ?', some_param,some_param)
  = customer.id
  = customer.name
  = customer.store.name
  = records.average(:grand_total)
  = records.sum(:grand_total)
```

I think there is one set of records to be eager loaded (`records` variable). But this would be a start. Can you try? a let me know which tables have the N+1 problem with this approach.

## Update: Eager loading monthly records for a given month

Rails gives you the possibility to eager load an association:

Model:

```
has_many :this_month_monthly_records,
  ->{ where('month_start > :start, month_start <= :start', start: your_month) },
  class_name: 'MonthlyRecord'
```

Controller:

```
@customers = Customer.
  select('customers.id,customers.name,monthly_records.grand_total,stores.name').
  includes(:store, :this_month_monthly_records).
  references(:stores, :monthly_records)
```

On view:

```
- @customers.each do |customer|
  - records = customer.this_month_monthly_records
  = customer.id
  = customer.name
  = customer.store.name
  = records.average(:grand_total)
  = records.sum(:grand_total)
```

The problem with this way is `your_month` variable. It's passed in `params` but I see no safe way to pass it to the model.

Comment: Thanks Juan - I think this might work.  Going to try it today and will feedback.